# Error Deserializing WCF POST Request With Multiple Parameters

Tags: c#, wcf

i did search before posting this question and none of the answers helped me

i am hosting a WCF web service on IIS and using GET and POST in it successfully. the error is only showing when calling a POST web method with multiple param

Example:

```
**//this fails**
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "test", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
String test(String p, String credential);


**//this works**
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",UriTemplate = "test")]
String test(String p);
```

*the code behind simply returns a string for testing*

**I am receiving the following error:**

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Error in deserializing body of request message for
>   operation 'test'. The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any
>   information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty =
>   true)

i am testing the following web methods on POSTMAN

Parameters passed are random string:

> p: tt
>
> credetial: ghdhdj

Comment: It would be useful to see the parameters passed through in both cases.  Could you update your question with them please?

Comment: i updated the question @Martin, but the param are not related...i suspect that BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest this is causing the issue but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: I'm sure this is a typo, but `crenetial` is not the same as `credential`. Could you verify this?

Comment: yes my mistake its a typo here.. but in the actual code its written correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF doesn’t support form-data by default, we merely pass the parameter by using the Wrapper element when we use Http_Post request.
As you mentioned, we should use the below code to wrap the multiple parameters.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    string GetData(string value,string value2);
```

And then we can pass the parameters with JSON format.

```
{"value":"ab","value2":"cd"}
```

Screenshot.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.